# Image isn't loaded from jar builded by gradle in JavaFX project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx-2, fxml

I made an app with JavaFX and it worked correctly when I build the project with the build button on IntelliJ IDE.
However it doesn't work when I run from jar file generated from gradle JavaFX project and the following error is shown on console.

```
$java -jar sample-menu-all.jar

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/myuser/MyProjectRoot/build/libs/sample-menu-all.jar!/images/main_menu/icon.svg (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:220)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:113)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at presentation.utils.ImageUtil.loadSvgImage(ImageUtil.java:23)
    at presentation.controller.MenuController.loadRegistrationButtonImage(MenuController.java:25)
    at presentation.controller.MenuController.initialize(MenuController.java:20)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3144)
    at presentation.navigator.VitalBitMenuNavigator.launchNewScene(VitalBitMenuNavigator.java:22)
    at presentation.navigator.VitalBitMenuNavigator.launchMenuStage(VitalBitMenuNavigator.java:33)
    at presentation.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/Users/myuser/MyProjectRoot/build/libs/sample-menu-all.jar!/fxml/menu.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3144)
    at presentation.navigator.VitalBitMenuNavigator.launchNewScene(VitalBitMenuNavigator.java:22)
    at presentation.navigator.VitalBitMenuNavigator.launchMenuStage(VitalBitMenuNavigator.java:33)
    at presentation.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.swing/javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(SwingFXUtils.java:77)
    at presentation.utils.ImageUtil.loadSvgImage(ImageUtil.java:30)
    at presentation.controller.MenuController.loadRegistrationButtonImage(MenuController.java:25)
    at presentation.controller.MenuController.initialize(MenuController.java:30)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 15 more
```

My directory structure is this

```
ProjectRootDir
|-- build
  |-- libs
    sample-menu-all.jar
|-- build.gradle
|-- src
  |-- main
    |-- java
      |-- presentation
        MainApp.java
        |-- controller
          |-- MenuController.java
        |-- navigator 
          |-- MenuNavigator.java
        |-- utils
          |-- ImageUtile.java
    |-- resources
      |-- fxml
        |-- menu.fxml
      |-- properties
        |-- string.properties
```

The gradle file, main.java and the class fxml is loaded are in the snnipet link.

#### build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.4'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'

mainClassName = 'presentation.MainApp'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // Camera lib
    compile 'com.github.sarxos:webcam-capture:0.3.12'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21'
    // RxJavaFX
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2"
    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    // Batik (for loading AVG)
    compile group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-transcoder', version: '1.10'
}


jfx {
    mainClass = 'MainApp'
    vendor = 'myVendor'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'presentation.MainApp'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

#### MainApp.java

```
package presentation;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import presentation.navigator.MenuNavigator;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    private MenuNavigator navigator;

    public MainApp() {
        navigator = new MenuNavigator();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        MainApp.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        navigator.launchMenuStage(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

#### MenuNavigator.java

```
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import presentation.utils.ResourceBundleUtf8Control;
import presentation.utils.config.Config;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MenuNavigator {

    private void launchNewScene(Stage stage, String $fxmlName) {
        try {
            URL location = getClass().getResource("/fxml/" + $fxmlName);
            ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties.string", Locale.getDefault(), new ResourceBundleUtf8Control());
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(location, resources);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, Config.loadDimen("dimension.app_screen_size.width"), Config.loadDimen("dimension.app_screen_size.height"));
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setTitle(Config.loadString("string.title"));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void launchMenuStage(Stage stage) {
        launchNewScene(stage, "menu.fxml");
    }
}
```

#### MenuContoroller.java

```
package presentation.controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import presentation.MainApp;
import presentation.utils.FileUtil;
import presentation.utils.ImageUtil;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MenuController extends BaseController implements Initializable {

    public Button userRegistrationButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        this.loadRegistrationButtonImage();
    }

    private void loadRegistrationButtonImage() {
        ImageView buttonImage = new ImageView();
        ImageUtil.loadSvgImage(buttonImage, "/images/main_menu/icon.svg", 71, 94);
        userRegistrationButton.setGraphic(buttonImage);
        userRegistrationButton.setGraphicTextGap(37.5);
    }

}
```

#### ImageUtile.java

```
package presentation.utils;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class ImageUtil {
    public static void loadSvgImage(ImageView target, String resourcePath, int withd, int height) {
        SvgTranscoder imageTranscoder = new SvgTranscoder();

        imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float) withd);
        imageTranscoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, (float) height);

        try {
            URL imagePath = ImageUtil.class.getResource(resourcePath);
            TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileReader(imagePath.getFile()));
            imageTranscoder.transcode(input, null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | TranscoderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedImage bimage =  imageTranscoder.getImage();
        WritableImage wimage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimage, null);
        target.setImage(wimage);
    }
}
```

#### SvgTranscoder.java

```
package presentation.utils;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class SvgTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {

    private BufferedImage image = null;

    @Override
    public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
        image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput out) {
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

The same code snippets are here too.
https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/3dab5b901e6aa5e861e3

I unpacked the jar file and checked fxml directory and files are included.
This is the screenshot.
[Unpacked jar files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQRR.png)

I would really appreciate if someone advise me on this problem.

Comment: If those links ever go stale, your question will be useless to future readers.  Edit your question and include the code for your `ImageUtil.loadSvgImage` method directly in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I moved the codes in snippet link to here and added the other codes related to the error message such as ImageUtile.java. 
I would appreciate if you advise me some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
new FileReader(imagePath.getFile())
```

Despite its name, the getFile() method of the URL class **does not** return a valid file name and does not convert a URL to a file.  (The method was introduced in Java 1.0, over twenty years ago, back when most URLs did in fact represent physical files on either the same computer or a different computer.)

Even if it did, a .jar file is a single archive—entries inside it are not files themselves, just subsequences of bytes representing compressed data.

You *must* refer to a resource in a .jar entry as a resource URL or its equivalent stream.  You must not attempt to convert it to a file.

Fortunately, you don’t need a file.  You can pass the URL directly, as a String:

```
URL imagePath = ImageUtil.class.getResource(resourcePath);
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(imagePath.toString());
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked well ! 
And I understood your description too. Thank you so much for the detail advice.